# How does $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{g}(0)$ gets satisfied in path lifting?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given continuous maps $f,g:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, and the quotient map $\pi: [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ satisfying $(f \circ \pi )(0)=(g \circ \pi )(0) $. How does this condition mean that we can lift $f$ and $g$ to maps $\tilde{f},\tilde{g}: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{g}(0)$.

[image]

Where $e: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^{1}$ s.t. $e(x)= (\cos(2 \pi x),\sin(2 \pi x))$.

Doubt:
I understand that $e(\tilde{f}(0)) = (f \circ \pi )(0) = (g \circ \pi )(0) =  
e(\tilde{g}(0)) $, but how does that lead to $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{g}(0)$?

Comment: The whole point is that you *can* lift $f$ and $g$ to maps with $\tilde{f}(0) = \tilde{g}(0)$. Obviously not every $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ must agree at $0$ - one may merely shift $\tilde{g}$

Comment: Your emphasis on "can" tells me that since $\tilde{f}(0)-\tilde{g}(0) \in \mathbb{Z}$, it can have value 0 as well. Is this the argument?

Comment: Denoting $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g}$ as lifts of $f,g$ is a bit "dirty". They are lifts of $f \circ \pi, g \circ \pi$ as shown in your diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The map $e$ is a covering projection and therefore a fibration, i.e. has the homotopy lifting property. For a map $\varphi : [0,1] \to S^1$ this implies that for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $e(t) = \varphi(0)$ there exists a lift $\tilde{\varphi}$ such that $\tilde{\varphi}(0) = t$. Hence you obtain lifts  $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g}$ as desired because you can take the same $t$ for $f, g$. However, $t$ is not unique. In fact, any $t \in  e^{-1}(\varphi(0))$ will do.

Usually $\pi$ is taken as the restriction $e \mid_{[0,1]}$ though there are many other choices. In that case $(f \circ \pi)(0) = f(1)$ and any $t \in  e^{-1}(f(1))$ will do.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Probably I over complicated it. But the key argument to my doubt is that for any $t \in \matgbb{R} $, there exists a unique lift. So, we choose the same $t$ for both $f, g$.

Comment: Not for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, but for any $t \in \varphi^{-1}(0)$ if you want to lift $\varphi$. This is a necessary condition because we must have $e(\tilde{\varphi(0)} = \varphi(0)$.